# Django ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' - No module named csrf

Tags: django, importerror, django-settings

I am just starting to fiddle around with django. First I made a small app on my windows machine and verified it worked fine
Then, I zipped the entire project, and opened the zip on a linux machine.
The linux machine was installed with mod_wsgi and django 1.1.1, of course.

I created the following dirs:

- `/usr/local/bin/ROOT` - contains only one file, `django.wsgi`
- `/usr/local/bin/ROOT/myapp` - root dir of django app

Per the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide), I added to `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName server
    ServerAlias server
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com


    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/bin/ROOT/django.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/bin/ROOT/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now per the instructions [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) I put in `/usr/local/bin/ROOT/django.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys
path = '/usr/local/bin/ROOT'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

If it is of any importance: there is nothing set on PYTHOHPATH before the application starts.

After that I did a graceful restart to apache, and went to server/myapp. I got a 500 error.
Lookin in the log I see:

```
[Sun Dec 05 12:24:17 2010] [error] [client XXXX] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.csrf: "No module named csrf"
```

What am I doing wrong? all other threads I found about this always either end up with a conclusion that it's an old version of django (but mine's 1.1.1) or that there are several apps running, but I have only one...

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"django.middleware.csrf" is the package in Django 1.2.x

For Django 1.1.x  CSRF settings read the appropriate docs [Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/csrf/)

The package in 1.1.x was "django.contrib.csrf.middleware.CsrfMiddleware"

Answer (score 1):

1.1.1 *is* an old version of Django (the current version is 1.2.3), and that's almost certainly the cause of your problem. There is no `django.middleware.csrf` in 1.1.1.